# iframe in jqtouch not scaling down the content?

Tags: iframe, jqtouch

I use jqtouch and I have an iframe in one of the divs that loads into the main page.
The problem is that the pdf in the iframe is not scaled down as it does in an iframe in an ordinary html page. You only see the top left corner of the content in the iframe.

So what in jqtouch is causing the content in the iframe not scaling down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure of the anwser. Not at all. But this could be related to the [viewport](http://developer.apple.com/safari/library/documentation/appleapplications/reference/safarihtmlref/articles/metatags.html) `<meta>`.